# Docker - Unable to push image to private registry

Tags: registry, docker, private

I have created my own private registry on my server by pulling and running the registry image.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry
```

After which, I tried to tag a simple image and push it to the server.

```
sudo docker tag ubuntu:latest localhost:5000/myprivateubuntu
```

And I received this error:

```
Error: Invalid registry endpoint ... Get ... If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add '--insecure-registry localhost:5000' to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/localhost:5000/ca.crt
```

Anyhow know what's the problem?

Comment: Have you read the error message, and added `--insecure-registry localhost:5000` to the daemon's arguments, and restarted the daemon?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

stop the service.

```
sudo service docker stop
```

restart service with `--insecure-registry` arguments:

```
/usr/bin/docker -d --insecure-registry localhost:5000
```

or edit `/etc/default/docker` file and add the following line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry localhost:5000"
```

Comment: Yes, same solution suggested here: http://wanderingquandaries.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/setting-up-insecure-docker-registry.html

Comment: I'm using Docker 1.7 and --insecure-registry appears to only work if I start the daemon directly. Editing `/etc/default/docker` or setting `DOCKER_OPTS` directly in the init script seems to have no effect.

Comment: I have the same error so I'm trying to fix it with the insecure flag but the command isn't recognized? `sudo service docker start -d --insecure-registry openshift
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  -d --insecure-registry openshift docker.service
/bin/systemctl: invalid option -- 'd'` (also without --d it's not possible)

Answer (score 2):

From comments of the accepted answer, it looks like the solution does not works for all. The following solution works for me.

#### Create `systemd` conf override file for Docker

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf
```

Add these following line and save it

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
```

#### Edit `/etc/default/docker`

```
sudo vi /etc/default/docker
```

Add the following line and save it. Replace `localhost:5000` with your registry domain name and port

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry localhost:5000"
```

#### Restart `docker` daemon

Reload overriden configuration and restart `docker` as follows

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Local insecure registry in docker along with proxy:

1) in ubuntu add the following flag --insecure-registry IP:port under DOCKER_OPTS in file /etc/default/docker

1.1) configure no_proxy env variable to bypass local IP/hostname/domainname...as proxy can throw a interactive msg ...like continue and this intermediate msg confuses docker client and finally timesout...

1.2) if domainname is configured...then don't forget to update /etc/hosts file if not using DNS.

1.3) in /etc/default/docker set the env variables http_proxy and https_proxy...as it enables to download images from outside company hubs. format http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port

2) restart the docker service...if installed as service, use sudo service docker restart

3) restart the registry container [sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 registry:2 ]

4) tag the required image using sudo docker tag imageid IP:port/imagename/tagname ifany

5) push the image ...sudo docker push ip:port/imagename

6) If u want to pull the image from another machine say B without TLS/SSL,then in B apply setps 1,1.1 and 
2. **If these changes are not done in machine B...pull will fail.**

Answer (score 0):

My solution, built on top of the prior ones.

```
# docker -v
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
# uname -a
Linux host 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Contents of my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "insecure-registries" : [
        "ipaddress:port"
      ],
    "experimental" : false,
    "debug" : true
}
```

where `ipaddress:port` is the dotted IPv4 address of the registry machine followed by the registry port (e.g. `127.0.0.1:12345`). I did not have to prefix with `http://` or anything like that.

No changes to `/etc/default/docker`

And then I reloaded and restarted the daemon with:

```
# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
# sudo systemctl restart docker
```

`docker push` to the insecure registry works now.