# Kubernetes deployment - specify multiple options for image pull as a fallback?

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, containers, registry

We have had image pull issues at one time or another with all of our possible docker registries including Artifactory, AWS ECR, and GitLab.   Even DockerHub occasionally has issues.

Is there a way in a Kubernetes deployment to specify that a pod can get an image from multiple different repositories so it can fall back if one is down?

If not, what other solutions are there to maintain stability?  I've seen things like Harbor and Trow, but it seems like a heavy handed solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way in a Kubernetes deployment to specify that a pod can get an image from multiple different repositories so it can fall back if one is down?

Not really, not natively . You could probably trick a K8s node to pull images from different image registries (one at a time) if you place them behind something like a TCP load balancer that directs traffic to multiple registries. But this might take a lot of testing and work.

> If not, what other solutions are there to maintain stability? I've seen things like Harbor and Trow, but it seems like a heavy handed solution to a simple problem.

I'd say either [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/), [Quay](https://quay.io/), and [Trow](https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/trow) is the way to go if you want something more redundant.

Kubernetes has the [ability](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) to set `ImagePullPolicy` and you can set it for example to `Never` if you'd like to pre-pull all your critical images on all the K8s nodes. You can tie this to some automation to pre-pull your images across your clusters and nodes.

I've actually opened a K8s [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93736) to see  if this idea gains traction.

*Update:*

If you're using [containerd](https://containerd.io/) or [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/) (or even [Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557384/docker-private-registry-with-mirror) has registry mirrors). You have the ability to configure mirror registries:

`containerd.toml` example

```
...
    [plugins.cri.registry]
      [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."local.insecure-registry.io"]
          endpoint = ["http://localhost:32000"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."gcr.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://gcr.io"]
      [plugins.cri.registry.configs]
        [plugins.cri.registry.configs.auths]
          [plugins.cri.registry.configs.auths."https://gcr.io"]
            auth = "xxxxx...."
...
```

[`cri-o.conf` example](https://medium.com/cri-o/default-container-registry-revisited-50b32dd808fe)

```
...
# registries is used to specify a comma separated list of registries to be used
# when pulling an unqualified image (e.g. fedora:rawhide).
registries = [
“registry.example.xyz”,
“registry.fedoraproject.org”
]
...
```

✌️

Comment: Awesome and very complete answer. Unfortunately, pretty much what I was expecting though, haha.  I appreciate the k8s feature request; upvoted.  It would be awesome to have a native solution here.

Comment: there are open bugs which makes docker registry-mirrors solution almost unusable, this : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30880  , means that you cannot use mirrors with authentication